# react-snap failed on dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, react-snap, react-ssr

error at /products/subcategory/WOMEN'S%20COATS: Error: Page crashed!
at Page._onTargetCrashed (/media/haider/DATA/Fabric/client/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:215:24)
at CDPSession. (/media/haider/DATA/Fabric/client/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:123:56)
at CDPSession.emit (events.js:400:28)
at CDPSession._onMessage (/media/haider/DATA/Fabric/client/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:200:12)
at Connection._onMessage (/media/haider/DATA/Fabric/client/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:112:17)
at WebSocket. (/media/haider/DATA/Fabric/client/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:44:24)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/media/haider/DATA/Fabric/client/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/media/haider/DATA/Fabric/client/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:400:28)
✅  crawled 6 out of 43 (/products/subcategory/WOMEN'S%20FASHION)
✅  crawled 53 out of 55 (/products/subcategory/WOMEN'S%20T-SHIRT)
✅  crawled 66 out of 67 (/products/subcategory/WOMEN'S%20HOODIES)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

My app has dynamic routes where API is made. But react-snap failed on some of the dynamic routes. Looking for any solution or suggestions to fix this. My app is working fine on these pages there is no error with the API calls.